# extract information from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way to transform an array looking like this:

```
Array ( [level-1] => 2 [quarter-1] => 1 [year-1] => 2014 [level-2] => 2 [quarter-2] => 2 [year-2] => 2015 [level-49] => 2 [quarter-49] => 2 [year-49] => 2015 [level-58] => 1 [quarter-58] => 1 [year-58]
```

and take only the numbers after the keywords to use them in an sql table. For example, the table would look like:

```
 ID 1 Level 2 Quarter 1 Year 2014 
 ID 2 level 2 quater 2 Year 2015
 ID 49 level 2 quarter 2 year 2015
```

Etc

I tried

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
        print_r ($_POST);
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        $s=$_POST;

        echo $abc= implode(',', $s);
        for($a=0;$a<count($s);$a++){
            $ar=explode(',',$abc);
            echo $var=$ar[$a];

        }
  }
```

But the result i get is something like :

```
2,1,2014,2,2,2015,2,2,2015...
```

I need also the ID to be shown. But i most importantly do not know how to interpret the results to put them in the db..

Comment: Did you try anything?Got any result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = array ( "level-1" => 2, "quarter-1" => 1, "year-1" => 2014, "level-2" => 2, "quarter-2" => 2, "year-2" => 2015, "level-49" => 2, "quarter-49" => 2, "year-49" => 2015, "level-58" => 1, "quarter-58" => 1, "year-58"=>2016);

foreach(array_chunk($array,3,true) as $val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
       if(strpos($k, "level") !== false){
           $temp    = explode("-",$k);
           $id      = $temp[1];
           $level   = $v;
       }
       if(strpos($k, "quarter") !== false){
           $quarter = $v;
       }
       if(strpos($k, "year") !== false){
           $year    = $v;
       }
    }
    echo "ID ".$id." Level ".$level." Quarter ".$quarter." Year ".$year;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output :

```
ID 1 Level 2 Quarter 1 Year 2014
ID 2 Level 2 Quarter 2 Year 2015
ID 49 Level 2 Quarter 2 Year 2015
ID 58 Level 1 Quarter 1 Year 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to code in PHP, so i will explain you the logic for doing it.

`for(int i=0;i<array.length;i=i+3)`
`{`

//`get value from array[i]; get the level-x field and retrieve the x value, then extract integers accordingly from it after keywords. In java StringTokenizer can be used for this, or regex etc`

//`again get value from array[i+1] and extract the integer`

//`get the value from array[i+2] and do the same as above.`

`}`

If the array is shuffled, you can match it with the level-x to get the exact tuple to insert. So level-x, the x value acts as an index that groups all related value.